# Instantiate HttpClient in another domain

Tags: c#, .net, httpclient

I'm trying to instantiate httpclient in another app-domain.
But im getting an exception when trying to instantiate WebRequestHandler.

Here is my code:

```
public class CipHandler : IDisposable
{
    private readonly HttpClient _client;
    private readonly WebRequestHandler _clientHandler;
    private readonly X509Store _certStore;
    private AppDomain _closedDomain;
....some other properties

    private void CreateDomain()
    {
        AppDomainSetup ads = new AppDomainSetup();
        ads.ApplicationBase = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;

        ads.DisallowBindingRedirects = false;
        ads.DisallowCodeDownload = true;
        ads.ConfigurationFile = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile;

        _closedDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("Closed Secure Domain", null, ads);
    }

    public CipHandler()
    {
        var certificate = GetCert();

        CreateDomain(); 

        _clientHandler = (WebRequestHandler)_closedDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(typeof(WebRequestHandler).Assembly.FullName, typeof(WebRequestHandler).FullName);  <<<<<EXCEPTION IS HERE
        _clientHandler.AutomaticDecompression = System.Net.DecompressionMethods.Deflate | System.Net.DecompressionMethods.GZip;
        _clientHandler.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true; 
        _clientHandler.ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual;
        _clientHandler.ClientCertificates.Add(certificate);

        _client = (HttpClient)_closedDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(typeof(HttpClient).Assembly.FullName, typeof(HttpClient).FullName, new object[] { _clientHandler });
        _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("text/xml"));

        OpenMarket = (OpenMarket)_closedDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(typeof(VoRoamInfo).Assembly.FullName, typeof(VoRoamInfo).FullName, new object[] { _client, certificate });
        VoFupInfo = (VoFupInfo)_closedDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(typeof(VoRoamInfo).Assembly.FullName, typeof(VoRoamInfo).FullName, new object[] { _client, certificate });
        VoRoamInfo = (VoRoamInfo)_closedDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(typeof(VoRoamInfo).Assembly.FullName, typeof(VoRoamInfo).FullName,new object[] { _client, certificate });
    }
```

Exception is: Type 'System.Net.Http.WebRequestHandler' in assembly 'System.Net.Http.WebRequest, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' is not marked as serializable.

Can someone help me understand that issue? 
IS there some other way to achieve httpclient on another app_domain?

Comment: Did you just copy the executable from one machine to another or publish application?  A Net library executable will not run unless the same version (and updates) are installed on both the build and deploy machine.  If you do not have same version of Net than you need to publish application and install using the setup.exe like any commercial software.  Publish updates the windows dlls on the deploy machine so the are equivalent to the build machine.

Comment: I dont understand what are you talking about. I'm trying to instantiate an class in new app domain. hence : _closedDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(typeof(WebRequestHandler).Assembly.FullName, typeof(WebRequestHandler).FullName);

Comment: Sorry.  It looked like library wasn't installed.  Not all Net library objects can be serialized..  The CreateInstanceAndUnWrap is using serialization and the object in Net cannot be serialized.  I've never tried serialize a HTTP Client, but got the same error lots of times with a Dictionary.  There are plenty of postings on serialized dictionary and maybe one of those solutions will help here.

Comment: The exception message **literally tells you what the problem is**. If you aren't going to bother reading it, nobody can help you.

Answer (score 1):

To be able to create an object in another `AppDomain`, the type to be instantiated must be either 1) derived from `MarshalByRefObject`, or 2) marked as `Serializable` with `SerializableAttribute`.

```
[Serializable]
public class SerializableClass
{
}
```

The exception is because `WebRequestHandler` is neither.